# Replacing space after subsection title with a full stop

Tags: spacing, sectioning, subsection

> How can I replace the space after the subsection title with a full stop?

[image: Screenshot]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

   \makeindex[intoc]
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeatletter

\let\@ssect@ORIG\@ssect
\let\@runin@ssect\@ssect

\apptocmd{\@runin@ssect}{%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
   % Comment out the following line to remove “phantom number” indentation in
   % the TOC
   \protect\numberline{}% no number in TOC
   #5% the title
 }%
 \let\@ssect\@ssect@ORIG       % restore the normal \@ssect
}{}{\FAILED}

\newcommand*{\runinsubsection}{%
 \let\@ssect\@runin@ssect
 \@startsection{subsection}%
 {2}% level
 {\z@}% indentation of heading from the left margin
 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% absolute value = beforeskip
 {-1.5em \@plus -.1em}% when negative, opposite = skip to leave right of a
                      % run-in heading.
 {\normalfont\large\bfseries}% style
 *% we want an unnumbered subsection
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
   \runinsubsection{First}
       \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You load `titlesec`: why don't you use it?

Comment: It doesn't work with sectsy.

Comment: You never want to load both titlesec and sectsty

Comment: @egreg Right. I'll remove titlesec.

Comment: unrelated but `book` class has not got an option `twoside=true`  perhaps you intended `twoside`

Comment: @SahibaArora I'd remove `sectsty` instead.

Comment: @egreg I, unfortunately, don't have that choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much simpler than your attempt.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\runinsubsection}[1]{%
  \@startsection{subsection}%
  {2}% level
  {\z@}% indentation of heading from the left margin
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% absolute value = beforeskip
  {-1.5em \@plus -.1em}% when negative, opposite = skip to leave right of a
                       % run-in heading.
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}% style
  *%
  {#1.}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{x}
\subsection{y}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\runinsubsection{First}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a normal space after the period, use

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\runinsubsection}[1]{%
  \@startsection{subsection}%
  {2}% level
  {\z@}% indentation of heading from the left margin
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% absolute value = beforeskip
  {0pt}% when negative, opposite = skip to leave right of a
                       % run-in heading.
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}% style
  *%
  {#1. \hspace{0pt}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Any way to remove the extra space after the full stop?

Comment: @SahibaArora Added the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `titlesec` for that? It is quite easy:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside=true,11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fourier}
   \makeindex[intoc]
   \pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\subsection, }[runin]{\large\bfseries}{}{}{}[.]

\begin{document}

\subsection*{First} In former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because I don't want to get rid of `sectsty`.

Comment: However, titlesec is more powerful